# jqgrid - Can I set minimum width of a column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Can we set minimum width of a column in a re-sizable grid. 
Ok now you will why don't you make it resizable=false. 
Ans: If have a header "Customer Name" which is WIDTH=110, but sometimes the name are too big, so in that I should be able to resize only to increase the width of that column. And it SHOULD NOT allow to minimize the width.

Can take the example of http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover2-frozen.htm

Comment: use min-width ?

Comment: min-width on TH ? If yes, I tried that, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which allows such settings. The corresponding setting is introduced for auto-resizing functionality (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column)), but it will be applied for the manual resizing of columns by the user too. You need just add `autoResizing` property in the column, which should be object and specify `minColWidth` property of the object. For example

```
autoResizing: { minColWidth: 80 }
```

which restricts minimal width to 80px.

Comment: Well, I see it is working great in 4.8 or later versions. We still have 4.3 in production where it does not work. Is there some code I can put in javascript to make it work, that would be a great help.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since it works in latest versions. I am accepting this answer.

Comment: @Sudhir: The feature, like many other, not exist in the version 4.3. The resizing of columns is *rewrote* in free jqGrid. You can see this on the color of resizing bar and on the possibility to resize the last column of the grid. There are no simple possibility to set any min width of column in the retro version of jqGrid. **Please, include the version of jqGrid and the fork which you use in every your question.** If you add "free-jqgrid" tag to the question and includes the demo, which uses free jqGrid then I suppose that you really use it.